# Laravel 5 - DropzoneJS: Request object is empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I've decided to upgrade a website from Laravel 4.3 to Laravel 5.1 and I'm facing a strange problem.

I'm trying to upload some pictures using the DropzoneJS library. I'm telling this library: "Before sending the pictures to `/pictures/store` (with an Ajax POST method), adds the `album_id` parameter to the request".

This part is working but in my `PictureController`, the `store` action is taking a `Request` object that remains empty instead of containing all inputs and many other things.

View:

```php
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/pictures/store', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'myAwesomeDropzone']) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('album_id', $album->id) !!} // Gives a correct value here
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

JS:

```js
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    paramName : 'file',
    maxFilesize : 8, // Mo
    acceptedFiles : 'image/*',
    headers : {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : token
    },
    sending : function(file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append('album_id', $('form input[name=album_id]').val()); // Still a correct value here
    },
    success : function(file, response) {
        console.log(response); // Will display the Request object (see controller)
    },
    error : function(file, error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PictureController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {

        return response()->json(['request' => $request]); // Returns the Request object

    }

}
```

Here is my Request object:

[image: Request object]

Not containing anything... And the Ajax request:

```
-----------------------------98052356720717
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="album_id"

1
-----------------------------98052356720717
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"

It1DQQiXuiLJGwgJwx5UVXe1QEP7TsC1uovglxD2
```

Comment: Just curious, how are you catering for the URL parameter of dropzone? I have something like : url: "{{route('addFileEntry', [])}}",  - perhaps you need to add something similar like that?

Comment: Dropzone automatically gets the url by inspecting the `<form>` element. I don't think the route is the problem here, because the correct controller/action is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a solution but I'm pretty sure this isn't the best one.

In my `PictureController` instead of getting the `album_id` parameter like this:

```php
$request->input('album_id')
```

I used the `Input` facade like that (Laravel 4's style):

```php
Input::get('album_id')
```

And I don't know why, but it works ! If you have a better solution, be sure that I will pick your answer as the best one. Meanwhile, mine is the best :D